# convert a multi-level column index to a column

Tags: python, pandas

here's an example df2,

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={"data_provider": ["prov_a", "prov_a", "prov_a", "prov_a", "prov_a", "prov_a"],
          "indicator": ["ind_a", "ind_a", "ind_a", "ind_b", "ind_b", "ind_b"],
          "unit": ["EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR"],
          "year": ["2017", "2018","2019", "2017","2018","2019"],
          "country1": [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6],
          "country2": [4, 5, 6, 40, 50, 60]}
)

df1MultiIndex = df1.pivot_table(
    index=['data_provider', 'indicator', 'unit'],
    columns='year'
)
df1MultiIndex.columns.names = ['Country', 'Year']

df2 = df1MultiIndex[[('country2', '2017')]]
# Country                      country2
# Year                             2017
# data_provider indicator unit
# prov_a        ind_a     EUR         4
#               ind_b     EUR        40
#
# MultiIndex([('country2', '2017')],
#            names=['Country', 'Year'])
```

I wish to convert `level=Year` column index to normal column.

The first step I can think of is to drop it using `droplevel`

```py
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(level='Year')
# Country                       country2
# data_provider indicator unit          
# prov_a        ind_a     EUR          4
#               ind_b     EUR         40
#
# Index(['country2'], dtype='object', name='Country')
```

but how to add a new column with the values from the dropped column level?
It should look like as below:

```py
Country                             country2
                              Year
data_provider indicator unit  
prov_a        ind_a     EUR   2017       4
              ind_b     EUR   2017      40
```

2022/12/23

add a new df,

```py
dict = {('D', '', ''): {1: '10%', 4: '30%'},
        ('P', '', ''): {1: 'Sugar', 4: 'Sugar'},
        ('t', '', ''): {1: 'Salt', 4:'Salt'},
        ('ra', '5G', 'W'): {1: '35%', 4:'28%'},
        ('rb', '5G', 'W'): {1: '-10%', 4:'30%'},
        ('sc', '5G', 'W'): {1: '-10%', 4:'25%'}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
df.columns.names = ['H', 'C', 'T']

# H    D      P     t   ra    rb    sc
# C                     5G    5G    5G
# T                      W     W     W
# 1  10%  Sugar  Salt  35%  -10%  -10%
# 4  30%  Sugar  Salt  28%   30%   25%
```

is there a easier way to get the df shown as below:

```py
H    D      P     t  C  ra    rb    sc
T                        W     W     W
1  10%  Sugar  Salt  5G 35%  -10%  -10%
4  30%  Sugar  Salt  5G 28%   30%   25%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `stack`

```
df2.stack(level=1)

Country                            country2
data_provider indicator unit Year          
prov_a        ind_a     EUR  2017         4
              ind_b     EUR  2017        40
```

Use `reset_index` if you want it as a column

```
df2.stack(level=1).reset_index(level=3)


Country                       Year  country2
data_provider indicator unit                
prov_a        ind_a     EUR   2017         4
              ind_b     EUR   2017        40
```

Comment: level can be a str. `df2.stack(level='Year').reset_index('Year')`

Comment: hi, I add a new df in the question description. please take a look and I'll appreciate if you can offer a eaiser method to get df with the format I expect.

Comment: @missmango `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(1)`